# awk command for file management

Tags: linux, awk

I have one file which contains several lines of data

```
editPin -pin phy_inst/i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[0] ctrl_soft_phy_inst/hbm_ch_tile_4_hbm_tile_inst/o_phy_row_cmd_p1[0] -assign {1443.0305 184.62} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
editPin -pin phy_inst/i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[1] ctrl_soft_phy_inst/hbm_ch_tile_4_hbm_tile_inst/o_phy_row_cmd_p1[0] -assign {1444.0305 185.62} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
```

and i want to perform some operation and i want to set my line like this

```
eval editPin -pin i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[0]  -assign { 0 [ expr 1443.0305 184.62]} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
eval editPin -pin i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[1]  -assign { 0 [ expr 1444.0305 185.62]} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
```

I used these commands individually, I tried them, and it worked how I wanted the structure.

```
awk '{$4=""; print $0}' all_pin 
awk '{print "eval " $0}' all_pin 
sed -e /^editPin/'{ s#phy_inst/## ; s/{/{ 0 [ expr / ; s/}/]}/ ; }' all_pin
```

but when i used these commands together its not giving the result how i want

```
cat all_pin | awk '{$4=""; print $0}' all_pin | awk '{print "eval " $0}' all_pin | sed -e /^editPin/'{ s#phy_inst/## ; s/{/{ 0 [ expr / ; s/}/]}/ ; }' all_pin
```

may i know the solution for this

and i want to perform addition operation for this block

```
-assign { 0 [ expr 1443.0305 362.764+X]}
```

***X*** is a constant value and i want to add ***X*** to ***362.764***
using command.I tried but I got the wrong answer

```
awk '{print $10+100}' all_pin
```

please help me to get out of this

The solution what i have is

```
awk -v X=10000 -f SE.awk all_pin

###  SE.awk ###
 {  for(i=1; i<=NF ; i++ ) {
        if ( $i ~ /^phy_inst/ ) {
                $i=substr($i,10) ;
                $(i+1)="" ; }
        if ( $i == "-assign" ) {
                $(i+1)="{ 0 [ expr " $(i+1) ;
                $(i+2)=$(i+2) + X " ]}" ;
                }
 }
        $1 = "eval " $1 ;
         print ;
 }
```

but i am trying to write individual commands using multiple awk and sed commands please guide me with the best commands to remove **phy_inst/*** from the line and to perform an arithmetic operation for  ***-assign { 0 [ expr 1444.0305 185.62]}*** line

to remove **phy_inst/*** i tried this command

```
awk -F 'editPin/ ' '{print substr($3,10) $0}' all_pin
```

perform arithmetic operations i have no idea please guide me for this

Answer (score 0):

Your endless pipe doesn't work that way; you're not modifying your file but always work on the original file, and your results are being discarded.

Given your input has always the same, given above structure, try `awk` in one go:

```
awk -v X=10000 '
        {$7 += X
         $7 =  $7 "]}"
         $6 =  "{ 0 [ expr " substr($6,2)
         $4 =  ""
         sub(/phy_inst\//,"")
         print "eval " $0
        }
' CONVFMT="%8.2f" file
eval editPin -pin i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[0]  -assign { 0 [ expr 1443.0305 10184.62]} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
eval editPin -pin i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[1]  -assign { 0 [ expr 1444.0305 10185.62]} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
```

It operates on the individual fields as desired, adds the `X` value to the seventh field,  appends the `"]}"`, and then prints out the result with the leading `"eval"`.